# Folder selection using browse button in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Is there any way to select upto folder (Folder selction) using Browse button in JSP?

Description: I want to select folder path from Browse button in my project. I dont want to select particular file from folder. I only want upto folder path.Is there any simplest way to do this?

```
  <TR height="45x">
                            <TD width="20%" align="right"><form:label path="ClientDestPath"><spring:message text="Client Prerequisites Destination Folder Path :" />
                                </form:label>
                            </TD>
                            <TD width="20%" align="left"><input path="ClientDestPath" type="file" name="fileUpload" value=""/></TD>
                                <TD></TD>
                        </TR>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot do that using JSP. You can select a file using the `file` type `input` element, but also cannot control its contents.

Comment: Thats why I am asking is there any different way to select upto Folder path rather than selecting file..?Because in my project, I want to do this .

Comment: @ManishDoshi: No, you simply can't. Web doesn't work the same way as desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are telling it's `JSP`,it is HTML and  it Can't be done with  HTML  or JavaScript for security reasons,Since they both have no access to the file system.